# How to prevent update if validation rules are not successfully passed?

Tags: apex, validation-rule

Is it possible to check, before update an object, if the validation rules for this object are respected ?

I try to update some objects and I have the error below :

> FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION

I want to add a test to check if the validation rules are respected and only in that case update the object.

Comment: You can't ever bypass validation rules, so there is no need for a pre check.

Comment: So, the only way to know if there is something wrong with the validation rules is to catch the exception ?

Comment: Greenstork's answer describes the basic mechanism. No need to catch exceptions. Just examine the SaveResult from the partial save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is how validation rules work, and they are respected by apex. If a validation rule fails, your DML will fail too. You can use the all or none option to allow the DML to work for those records that do work and fail for the others.

```
Database.SaveResult[] result = Database.Insert(accounts, false);
```

Comment: That is the command I use. But I need to know before the database operation if my object respect the validation rules. And it looks impossible !